# How do I trigger the payment process in EPiServer Commerce 8?

Tags: episerver, episerver-8

I'm working on an EPiServer 8 MVC implementation and I can't see how to trigger the payment process.

I've got my payment provider registered in Commerce Manager and I'm adding a payment to my OrderForm, Accepting Changes on the Cart, running the CartCheckoutWorkflow and saving the Cart as a Purchase Order but at no point in my payment provider triggered.

I've got the EPiServer.Commerce.Sample site from Commerce 7.5 but I cannot see how and where the payment provider is invoked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stepping through the workflows. I had the same problem and it turned out that there where no items in stock. This triggered the line item to be deleted from my order and the price to be 0. When it is 0, the paymentprovider is never called.

Comment: Turns out you're right. It was an inventory issue. Not sure why you got a down vote though.